# After checking response, send a second response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I receive the response from server for one string,then i want to send the next json object. I want to check the first object and send the second accordingly. How can response on the server?

```js
app.post('/demo', (request, response) => {
    const data = {"name": "john", "surname": "doe"};
    const check = "Schedulable";
    
    if(check == "Schedulable"){
      response.send(check);       //I need to know if it is schedulable on client-side. Because i will use this information on client-side. How can i send string information. After that i want to send json object.
      response.json(data);
    }
    else{
      response.send("Not Schedulable");
    }    
    
});
Client-side Code:
{
    const response = await fetch('/demo', options);
    const info = await response.json();
    
    //Normally i do this when i receive a single response. How can i do when i have double response.
}
```

Comment: You cant send two responses from the server.

Comment: instead of `response.send(check);  response.json(data);`, you can send `response.json{ 'check': check, 'data' : data }`

Comment: and for this `response.send("Not Schedulable");` you can send `response.json({ 'check': "Not Schedulable", data: {}  });` and then try to handle it in the client side.

Comment: @kgangadhar Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send an object containing both variables instead of sending them as separate pieces which you can’t do. For example:

```
{ check: check, data: data }
```

Or you could even use the shorthand and go:

```
{ check, data }
```

I hope this helps. I’m quite new to this myself.